# C++, OpenCV: Fastest way to read a file containing non-ASCII characters on windows

Tags: c++, file, opencv, buffer

I am writing a program using OpenCV that shall work on Windows as well as on Linux. Now the problem with OpenCV is, that its `cv::imread` function can not handle filepaths that contain non-ASCII characters on Windows. A workaround is to first read the file into a buffer using other libraries (for example std-libraries or Qt) and then read the file from that buffer using the `cv::imdecode` function. This is what I currently do. However, it's not very fast and much slower than just using `cv::imread`. I have a TIF image that is about 1GB in size. Reading it with `cv::imread` takes approx. 1s, reading it with the buffer method takes about 14s. I assume that `imread` just reads those parts of the TIF that are necessary for displaying the image (no layers etc.). Either this, or my code for reading a file into a buffer is bad.

Now my question is if there is a better way to do it. Either a better way with regard to OpenCV or a better way with regard to reading a file into a buffer.

I tried two different methods for the buffering, one using the std libraries and one using Qt (actually they both use QT for some things). They both are equally slow.:

### Method 1

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> readFileIntoBuffer(QString const& path) {

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    std::ifstream file(path.toStdWString(), std::iostream::binary);
#else
    std::ifstream file(path.toStdString(), std::iostream::binary);
#endif
    if (!file.good()) {
        return std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>>(new std::vector<char>());
    }
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::eofbit);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos length(file.tellg());
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> buffer(new std::vector<char>(static_cast<std::size_t>(length)));
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(length) == 0) {
        return std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>>(new std::vector<char>());
    }
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    try {
        file.read(buffer->data(), static_cast<std::size_t>(length));
    } catch (...) {
        return std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>>(new std::vector<char>());
    }
    file.close();
    return buffer;
}
```

And then for reading the image from the buffer:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> buffer = utility::readFileIntoBuffer(path);
cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(*buffer, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

### Method 2

```cpp
QByteArray readFileIntoBuffer(QString const & path) {
    QFile file(path);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return QByteArray();
    }
    return file.readAll();
}
```

And for decoding the image:

```cpp
QByteArray buffer = utility::readFileIntoBuffer(path);
cv::Mat matBuffer(1, buffer.size(), CV_8U, buffer.data());
cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(matBuffer, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

## UPDATE

### Method 3

This method maps the file into memory using `QFileDevice::map` and then uses `cv::imdecode`.

```cpp
            QFile file(path);
            file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
            unsigned char * fileContent = file.map(0, file.size(), QFileDevice::MapPrivateOption);
            cv::Mat matBuffer(1, file.size(), CV_8U, fileContent);
            cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(matBuffer, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

However, also this approach didn't result in a shorter time than the other two. I also did some time measurements and found that reading the file in the memory or mapping it to the memory is actually not the bottleneck. The operation that takes the majority of the time is the `cv::imdecode`. I don't know why this is the case, since using `cv::imread` with the same image only takes a fraction of the time.

### Potential Workaround

I tried obtaining an 8.3 pathname on Windows for files that contain non-ascii characters using the following code:

```cpp
QString getShortPathname(QString const & path) {
#ifndef Q_OS_WIN
    return QString();
#else
    long length = 0;
    WCHAR* buffer = nullptr;
    length = GetShortPathNameW(path.toStdWString().c_str(), nullptr, 0);
    if (length == 0) return QString();
    buffer = new WCHAR[length];
    length = GetShortPathNameW(path.toStdWString().c_str(), buffer, length);
    if (length == 0) {
        delete[] buffer;
        return QString();
    }
    QString result = QString::fromWCharArray(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;
    return result;
#endif
}
```

However, I had to find out that 8.3 pathname generation is disabled on my machine, so it potentially is on others as well. So I wasn't able to test this yet and it does not seem to provide a reliable workaround. I also have the problem that the function doesn't tell me that 8.3 pathname generation is disabled.

Comment: A somewhat intrusive way would be to create a symbolic link to the file, and go through that instead. If 8.3 pathname generation isn't disabled on the target machine, you could also call [GetShortPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx), and use that. I believe short pathnames do not contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Can you test on a another format like png?

Comment: @ IInspectable Thaks for the idea, that would indeed be an option. What do you mean with "If 8.3 pathname generation isn't disabled on the target machine"?
@ Miki I could, although it is rather hard to get a png bloat up to such a big size. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: You can [disable 8.3 file name creation on NTFS partitions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007). In that case, `GetShortPathName` cannot be used. See [Short vs. Long Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#short_vs._long_names) for additional details.

Comment: Ok, I just checked on my machine; apparently 8.3 pathname generation is disabled. However, I still tried to implement a function for getting the short path name. Now, instead of returning length 0 (as is done in case of errors), the function returns the original filepath. Now, how am I able to determine weather 8.3 pathname generation is enabled or disabled from within my program? Anyways, this solution apparently doesn't really help. Assumably, 8.3 pathname generation is disabled on many systems. I added the code I used to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open ticket on this in OpenCV GitHub: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4292

One of the comments there suggest a workaround without reading the whole file to memory by using memory-mapped file (with help from Boost):

```
mapped_file map(path(L"filename"), ios::in);
Mat file(1, numeric_cast<int>(map.size()), CV_8S, const_cast<char*>(map.const_data()), CV_AUTOSTEP);
Mat image(imdecode(file, 1));
```

Comment: Not a bad idea; this would, however, mean that I have to add boost to my Project just for that. But thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @user1488118: You could use [QFileDevice::map](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#map) (or [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html)::map) to create a file mapping object, since you are using Qt already.

Comment: I did a quick implementation using QFileDevice::map, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be faster at all. I'll have to do some detailed time measurements as soon as I've got time for that.

Comment: I did some measurements and found that the bottleneck is `cv::imdecode` and not the buffering/mapping of the image. I updated the question accordingly.